# Cross reference in section title broken in header

Tags: sectioning, hyperref, header-footer, cross-referencing

I've tried searching and can't find this anywhere, but sorry if it's been asked before.

I'm using the `memoir` class to write a thesis using LaTeX (which I'm fairly new to) and I've got a section in my appendix with some solutions to an equation, so I've titled the section using

```
\section{Solutions to equation in section~\ref{sec:xxxxx}}
```

This displays as it should at the start of the section, so the cross-reference isn't broken, but in the header at the top of odd pages the reference doesn't work; it prints as

> A.2. SOLUTIONS TO EQUATION IN SECTION ??

I can't find any way to fix this, short of manually changing it using `%\sectionmark{}` or removing the cross-reference.

Can anyone give me some suggestions?

Edit: It turns out the `hyperref` package is causing the problems (if I disable that package it works). I need hyperlinks to external websites in the document so I can't disable the `hyperref` package. I'm looking for solutions online but I'd appreciate any help in the meantime.

EDIT BY LOCKSTEP: Here's a MWE showing the problem. Note that the problem is not related to the `memoir` class -- it also shows up with `article` (if one uses `\pagestyle{headings}`).

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\section{foo}\label{sec:foo}

\cleardoublepage

\section{Solutions to equation in section~\ref{sec:foo}}

\end{document}​
```

Comment: The following example works for me (compile two times!): `\documentclass{memoir}\begin{document}\section{foo}\label{sec:foo}\cleardoublepage\section{Solutions to equation in section~\ref{sec:foo}}\end{document}​`

Comment: I tried that and it worked, so I gradually added in the packages that I'm using in my thesis and it turns out hyperref is causing the problems (if I disable that package it works). I need hyperlinks to external websites in the document so I can't disable the hyperref package. I'm looking for solutions online but I'd appreciate any help in the meantime.

Comment: It looks like it's linked to the fact that the default headers in the memoir class use all uppercase characters - changing the label to uppercase seems to fix it and will be sufficient for me. Thanks for the help with tracking this down!

Comment: I can't self answer yet (needs to be eight hours after my post as I have fewer than 10 reputation points) so I'll add my solution to my orignal post for now.

Comment: I forgot about the self-answer limit. Please be sure to revisit tex.sx in a few days and add a self-answer then -- it's not only about my potential upvote, but about maintaining the proper Q+A format (i.e., questions and answers in separate posts).

Comment: See [Hyperref within hyperref](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84487/hyperref-within-hyperref).

Comment: I don't see how http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84487/hyperref-within-hyperref relates to this question. I am not using hyperref and still had this problem. The \nouppercaseheads answer below fixed it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It seems to be linked to the fact that the default headers in the memoir class use all uppercase characters - changing the label to uppercase fixes it. Another option is to use `\nouppercaseheads` to change the headers so they are no longer uppercase.

Comment: This is really crazy! Thank you. I had the same problem. It seems to happen whenever `ref` is used in section titles that are uppercase. To clarify for anyone else. Change your label from `\label{sec:foo}` to `\label{SEC:FOO}`. This solves the problem despite how odd it is.