# Cross-referencing in Chapter Short Title

Tags: cross-referencing, chapters

In my thesis, I have an appendix of supplementary files for a chapter with \label{c:ch3}.

In the appendix file, I have used the chapter name as-

```
\chapter[Supplementary Material for Chapter \ref{c:ch3}]{Supplementary Material for Chapter \ref{c:ch3}}
\label{a:SM_ch3}
```

The chapter name appears properly with the correct title as shown in the following figure.

[image]

However, in the subsequent pages, in the short title of the chapter, the cross-referencing does not show.

[image]

How to fix this?

Comment: Please post a complete minimal example which demonstrates the problem. https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/99712/cross-reference-in-section-title-broken-in-header (possible duplicate but who knows without code?) or https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84487/hyperref-within-hyperref (not a duplicate question, but see comment).