# How do I reference in appendix a theorem given in the body?

Tags: cross-referencing, numbering, theorems, appendices

I have a theorem given in the body text of a paper, say Theorem 2 with label {theorem-abc}.
I would like to provide the proof of this theorem in the appendix.

1) How do I cross-reference this theorem in the appendix section title?

The section title that I want is "Proof of Theorem 2".

2) How do I restate the theorem again in the aforementioned section?

What I want is "Theorem 2. xxxxxxx", followed by its proof.

ADD: The document class file has following definitions regarding Appendix.

```
\def\appendix{\par
\section*{APPENDIX}
\setcounter{section}{0}
\setcounter{subsection}{0}
\def\thesection{\Alph{section}} }
```

I found similar issues [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84487/hyperref-within-hyperref). But it did not solve my Problem 1) either.

MWE: The class file is downloadable [here](http://www.vldb.org/pvldb/format_guide/vldb.cls).

```
\documentclass{vldb}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}
\section{Test Section}
\begin{theorem}
Test theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{restatable}[Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]{theorem}{fta}
\label{thm:FTA}
Every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least    one complex root. 
\end{restatable}

\appendix
\section[Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]{Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:FTA} (See page~\pageref{thm:FTA})}
\fta*
\begin{proof}
Assume...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

Comment: A [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) would, among other things, reveal *which* class you're using.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

2- You can use the `restatable` environment provided by [`thmtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/thmtools).

1- Since the environment generates an anchor, you can use the standard `\label`, `\ref` (`\pageref`) mechanism for cross-referencing.

A complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools, thm-restate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\begin{theorem}
Test theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{restatable}[Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]{theorem}{fta}
\label{thm:FTA}
Every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root. 
\end{restatable}

\appendix
\section[Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]{Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:FTA} (See page~\pageref{thm:FTA})}
\fta*
\begin{proof}
Assume...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Now that the question has been edited, and the used document class is known, here's a solution using the `vldb` document class (the link to the class can be found in the question):

```
\documentclass{vldb}
\usepackage{textcase}
\usepackage{thmtools,thm-restate}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\makeatletter
\def\@sect#1#2#3#4#5#6[#7]#8{%
    \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth
        \let\@svsec\@empty
    \else
        \refstepcounter{#1}%
        \edef\@svsec{%
            \begingroup
                %\ifnum#2>2 \noexpand\rm \fi % changed to next 29 July 2002 gkmt
                        \ifnum#2>2 \noexpand#6 \fi
                \csname the#1\endcsname
            \endgroup
            \ifnum #2=1\relax .\fi
            \hskip 1em
        }%
    \fi
    \@tempskipa #5\relax
    \ifdim \@tempskipa>\z@
        \begingroup
            #6\relax
            \@hangfrom{\hskip #3\relax\@svsec}%
            \begingroup
                \interlinepenalty \@M
                \if@uchead
                    \MakeTextUppercase{#8}% HERE
                \else
                    #8%
                \fi
                \par
            \endgroup
        \endgroup
        \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
        \vskip -12pt  %gkmt, 11 aug 99 and GM July 2000 (was -14) - numbered section head spacing
\addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
            \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
                \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
            \fi
            #7%
        }%
    \else
        \def\@svsechd{%
            #6%
            \hskip #3\relax
            \@svsec
            \if@uchead
                \uppercase{#8}%
            \else
                #8%
            \fi
            \csname #1mark\endcsname{#7}%
            \addcontentsline{toc}{#1}{%
                \ifnum #2>\c@secnumdepth \else
                    \protect\numberline{\csname the#1\endcsname}%
                \fi
                #7%
            }%
        }%
    \fi
    \@xsect{#5}\hskip 1pt
    \par
}
\makeatother

\declaretheorem{theorem}

\begin{document}

\section{Test Section}
\begin{theorem}
Test theorem
\end{theorem}

\begin{restatable}[Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]{theorem}{fta}
\label{thm:FTA}
Every non-constant single-variable polynomial with complex coefficients has at least one complex root. 
\end{restatable}

\appendix
\section[Proof of the Fundamental Theorem of Algebra]{Proof of Theorem~\ref{thm:FTA}}
\fta*
\begin{proof}
Assume...
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

### Explanation:

The problem is that `vldb.cls` sets the section (and also part) titles in upper case and uses the old TeX `\uppercase` command to this end; this will produce problems if special commands, such as `\ref`, are inside the argument of `\section` (or `\part`) since `\uppercase` don't recognize them as special commands and tretas them in the wrong way (the LaTeX command `\MakeUppercase` will also behave bad in this regard). To correct this situation, one can redefine (or patch) the internal command `\@sect`, to use `\MakeTextUppercase` (from the `textcase` package), instead of the problematic `\uppercase` command. In the example code above, the change was signaled with `% HERE`.

Comment: I followed your example, but encountered a problem. "2" in "Proof of Theorem 2" appeared as "?" (I had tried compiling the document many times). Would this be an issue of the document class file?

Comment: @jason.Z please see my updated answer.

Comment: Is there a way to restate a theorem on a different tex file?

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I use `\cref` instead of `\ref` in the appendix and it shows "??" after rendering. Is there a way to fix it?