# Restatable Does not Show Theorem Number

Tags: theorems, thmtools, appendix, ref

I learned about restatable from [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114151/how-do-i-reference-in-appendix-a-theorem-given-in-the-body) answer. However, when I put the theorem in the appendix, its reference does not have a number. Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\begin{restatable*}{theorem}{thm}
  Everybody knows that $1 + 1 = 2$.
\end{restatable*}

I would like this \ref{thm} to display A.1.

\appendix
\section{Proofs}
\thm\label{thm}
\begin{proof}
  Proof is trivial.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move the `\label{thm}` into `restatable*` environment:

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{thmtools} 
\usepackage{thm-restate}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}[section]
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}


\begin{restatable*}{theorem}{thm}\label{thm} % <<< \label moved to here
  Everybody knows that $1 + 1 = 2$.
\end{restatable*}

I would like this \ref{thm} to display A.1.

\appendix
\section{Proofs}
\thm
\begin{proof}
  Proof is trivial.
\end{proof}

\end{document}
```

[image]