# Put references inside subsection

Tags: hyperref

I have tried to add a reference to an appedix inside a subsection title. When I compile it appears a ?? and there is a link to the right place but I want in the link the number of the appendix and not the ??. Am I doing something wrong?

The code is:

```
\subsubsection{4 Herculis \ref{fig.A.1}}
```

The appendix:

```
\appendix
\section{Espectros red 150 lin/mm}\label{ap.A}

\subsection{4 Herculis}
```

and the error message:

```
 Reference `fig.A.1' on page 32 undefined on input line 677.
 Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\<def>-command' on input line 677. Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\<def>-command'
 Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\@refundefined' on input line 677. Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\@refundefined'
 Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\<def>-command' on input line 677. Token not allowed in a PDF string (PDFDocEncoding):(hyperref)                removing `\<def>-command'
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Also, see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84487.

Comment: Seems that you have not defined a `\label{fig.A.1}`. If you have please show the code ...

Answer (score 2):

The following example works without warnings and errors:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{4 Herculis \ref{fig.A.1}}
\begin{figure}
\caption{Caption of figure}
\label{fig.A.1}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Perhaps you are using version of `hyperref` that is too old. The current version is 2012/11/06 v6.83m.